Jupyter swap fee settings
please tell me how I can accept commissions fee for any swaps in my application in SOL/USDT. What if the pair does not contain sol/usdt, do I need to create 1000 token accounts in my jupiter referral account?
I mean this
const [feeAccount] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
[
Buffer.from("referral_ata"),
referralAccountPublicKey.toBuffer(),
inputMintPublicKey.toBuffer(), // can always be SOL/USDT for any swaps?
],
new PublicKey("REFER4ZgmyYx9c6He5XfaTMiGfdLwRnkV4RPp9t9iF3")
);
inputMintPublicKey.toBuffer(),
Thank you
